# How to use VAOs in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I've read that using VAOs is recommended but I don't know how.
I am using the tegra android development pack (which uses OpenGL ES 2.0) and I can't find the methodes glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArray. Are VAOs supported in ES 2.0 (without extensions)?

Also I don't understand what the benefit of a VAO is. Currently I compile the shaders and use glBindAttribLocation. After that I define the vertex positions and colors for a triangle and use glVertexAttribPointer. Then I just draw the triangle again and again.

This is the program (without error checks):

```
static void createProgram() {
    // vertex shader
    const char* vertexShaderCode = getVertexShaderCode();
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    const char* fragmentShaderCode = getFragmentShaderCode();
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // create program
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    // Dem Programm sagen, unter welchem Index die Daten der Shader Attribute liegen
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_pos");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "in_color");

    glLinkProgram(program);
}
```

And this is the triangle:

```
static void loadGeometry() {
    GLuint buffers[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
    GLuint vboPosition = buffers[0];
    GLuint vboColor = buffers[1];

    const int VERTEX_POSITION_BUFFER_SIZE = 12;
    const int VERTEX_POSITION_BUFFER_BYTESIZE = sizeof(GLfloat)* VERTEX_POSITION_BUFFER_SIZE;

    GLfloat vertexPositionBuffer[VERTEX_POSITION_BUFFER_SIZE] = {
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboPosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VERTEX_POSITION_BUFFER_BYTESIZE, vertexPositionBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Repeat for color...
}
```

And in the draw call I just do

```
glUseProgram(program);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Comment: If you don't use a VAO, you will have to manually bind the buffers, enable each attribute index you need, and disable each index you don't need. When you use a VAO, you only have to do all of that once, and they will be "recorded" by the VAO. Next time you want to draw an object, you only need to bind the VAO of that object. So basically using VAOs reduce the number of calls the CPU needs to make, and makes it easier to manage data related to individual mesh/objects

Comment: And it seems that VAOs are only supported for OpenGL ES 3.0. You'll have to use the extension here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_array_object.txt `GenVertexArraysOES()` `BindVertexArrayOES()`

Comment: Ah so I just haven't faced the benefits of a VAO yet because I only draw one static triangle I guess?

Comment: @Alex I know your answer dates quite some time back. Just for the record, the Khronos link regarding the `OES_vertex_array_object` extension notes that the requirement is **OpenGL ES 2.0** and not OpenGL ES 3.0. It looks that this function was implemented at a later point also for lower level hardware. The original GL 3.0 extension had the name `ARB_vao`. Whatever, this now leads to the somehow strange situation that we have support for VAOs in OpenGL ES 2.0 but not in OpenGL 2.x. ;-)